# Assign an array of values to a range

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I want to initiate a range of worksheet with an array of values. I have the following code.

```
function initiate(address, values) {
    return Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
        var range = sheet.getRange(address);
        var range.values = values;
        return ctx.sync()
    }
}
```

My tests show that this works **only when** `values` has exactly the same dimension (ie, height, width) as `address`, or when `values` is a single value. Otherwise, there will be an error.

Could anyone confirm that?

If so, I need to adjust `address` to suit the dimension of `values`. It is easy to get the dimension of `values`, but I cannot [find a function](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/worksheet.md) to get a range from eg, 1 top-left cell + 1 number of rows + 1 number of columns, or 1 top-left cell and 1 bottom-right cell.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA you would use [`Range.Resize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193274.aspx). In OfficeJS there seems to be a function called [getResizedRange](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/range.md#getresizedrangedeltarows-number-deltacolumns-number) which

> [g]ets a Range object similar to the current Range object, but with its bottom-right corner expanded (or contracted) by some number of rows and columns.

Unfortunately it accepts the *delta* values, so you need to calculate the difference between the current range size and the target size.
 For example, if you wanted to obtain a range of `rows` by `cols` cells, you could try something along the lines of

```
var originalRange = sheet.getRange(address);
var range = originalRange.getResizedRange(
     rows - originalRange.rowCount, cols - originalRange.columnCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

As CompuChip said, there is not (yet) an API for resizing a range to a particular *absolute* size, though it is forthcoming.

That said: if you have an array, just start with a single cell and then resize it by array's row-count-minus-1 (i.e., `array.length - 1`), followed by columns-minus-1 (`array[0].length - 1`)

```
const values = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    ["Hello", "Bonjour", "Привет"]
]

await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    const range = sheet.getRange("D3").getResizedRange(
        values.length - 1, values[0].length - 1);
    range.values = values;
    await context.sync();
});
```

You can try this snippet live in literally five clicks in the new Script Lab (https://aka.ms/getscriptlab). Simply install the Script Lab add-in (free), then choose "Import" in the navigation menu, and use the following GIST URL: https://gist.github.com/Zlatkovsky/6bc4a7ab36a81be873697cab0fa0b653.  See [more info about importing snippets to Script Lab](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/blob/master/README.md#import).